# Decrypt a fernet encryption

Tags: decrypt, encrypt

Hello,

I work with another team (who work on another technology) to develop an application.

In that application, we encrypt and decrypt data.

The other team would like to use [Fernet](https://github.com/fernet) to encrypt and decrypt data.

I have no experience with encrypt and decrypt.

I understand we use an alogirthm (AES128, AES192, AES256) to generate the private key (generated with Fernet) and to encrypt data. I will decrypt data with the same private key and the same algorithm?

My question is to know if Salesforce can decrypt with Fernet?

Comment: Fernet is using AES128 in CBC mode with a SHA256 HMAC so `Crypto` class in Apex can handle this. Give it a shot!

Comment: Thank you for your response.

To decrypt the value, I don't need to add the fernet library (I am not sure we can add a new library into Salesforce)?
I only need to use the method Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV()?

Comment: You can import a library if it's written in Apex (Salesforce's programming language), there are none for Fernet. The alternative is to implement the verification step in a [Function](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce-functions-quick-look/get-to-know-salesforce-functions)  and call it from your main code in Salesforce. Functions support Java, TypeScript and Node.JS. If you haven't worked with Apex and Salesforce, Function might be the way to go for you.

Comment: I know Salesforce and Apex but I didn't know Salesforce functions.
It means to be a good solution, I will try it, thanks.